# C# DateTime.Parse(someString)

Tags: parsing, datetime

I am working on a project and I get the following string representation of time and date, i.e. "00:02:52 APRIL 11, 2013 GMT". When I use the DateTime.Parse() method:

`DateTime dt= DateTime.Parse(dateString);`

`string text = dt.ToString("hh:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy ").ToUpper();`

My output (text) is:

"**05**:02:52 APR 11, 2013 GMT"

and NOT

"**00**:02:52 APR 11, 2013 GMT"

I don't get why the hour (HH) has changed to 00 to 05. I traced my code through V.S. many times. All I am doing is truncating the month, APRIL to APR.

Would anyone please give me insight on what I'm doing wrong or missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your local time zone setting, and see the code examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the hint Robert!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string dateString = "00:02:52 APRIL 11, 2013 GMT";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dateString).ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin! It works!
Sorry, apparently I need 15 reputations to give you +1 on your answer.

Comment: Hi David. I (noob) just joined SO. How do I mark Sachin's answer as Accepted?